# c# resize window over display resolution

Tags: c#, .net, resize, resolution

I am total newbie in .Net programming so be patient, please ;-).

I have problem with resizing window. I want to resize from my app other app's window and take screenshot of it. I do resizing based on this example: http://blogs.geekdojo.net/richard/archive/2003/09/24/181.aspx. But I have a problem. I work on a laptop with 1024x640 pixels screen resolution but I want to resize my window to 1200x1600 px. I can't do that couse display limitations. Is there any tricky solution to resize window for this resolution and take a screenshot of whole window? I've alos tried Sdesk program witch is suggested here: [Create Window larger than desktop (display resolution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445893/create-window-larger-than-desktop-display-resolution). Any help?

Comment: I answered the question in the post you referenced with code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8059990/302122 - you will need to use P/Invoke to call the appropriate method from C#

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you find a way to set a virtual resolution larger than your physical resolution (basically what sDesk does), and then let your application run normally on that large desktop. Depending on your video card, you might be able to configure the virtual resolution directly in the video driver, without using any additional utility.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. In fact you can't resize in any way the windows greater then the display size.

Just try it by position a window in normal mode (not minimized or maximized) somewhere on the left. Grab the right border of it and increase the width till the end of your screen. Now move the window, by grabbing the title bar, some more to the left. Repeat this procedure several times. At some point you're not able to get the window any wider anymore. If you now try to move the window till the right border hits the right side of your desktop, you'll see that the left border is direct at the left desktop side.